# Setting multiple Div colours according to collection of class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a class names **"MetroColor"**. Created a collection. And returned it in view as Div. Below is the Model,Controller and View.

```
public class MetroColors
    {
        public string ColorName { get; set; }
        public string ColorHexCode { get; set; }
        public string ColorRgbCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<MetroColors> listMetroColors = new List<MetroColors>();

            listMetroColors.Add(new MetroColors() { ColorName = "TURQUOISE", ColorHexCode = "#1abc9c", ColorRgbCode = "rgb(26, 188, 156)" });
            listMetroColors.Add(new MetroColors() { ColorName = "EMERALD", ColorHexCode = "#2ecc71", ColorRgbCode = "rgb(46, 204, 113)" });
            listMetroColors.Add(new MetroColors() { ColorName = "PETER RIVER", ColorHexCode = "#3498db", ColorRgbCode = "rgb(52, 152, 219)" });
            ViewBag.CreateColorList = listMetroColors;
            return View();
        }
```

View.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.CreateColorList)
{
    <div>@item.ColorName</div>
}
```

The div is getting created with the ColorNames. But I want the divs will get generate with the colours also, how it is mentioned inside the collection. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you were looking for this

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.CreateColorList)
{
    <div style="background: @item.ColorHexCode;">@item.ColorName</div>
}
```